# how to change jquery script for responsive iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, responsive-design, xhtml

I have a Blogger website : http://ildesign-blogger-demo-1.blogspot.fr

I have two problems with a script which would be very useful but i seems i did not understand its function. What i want : it should resize the youtube and vimeo iframes only in the .post-body.

The problems :

1. On the article page (type item page) it resizes all video iframes which are not only in the .post-body but on the page, for example in the footer. The page : http://ildesign-blogger-demo-1.blogspot.fr/2014/04/1st-article.html
2. On the list of the archive type of pages (archives by date), the video is not resized in the .post-body (but it should be), in the footer neither (that is ok). The page : http://ildesign-blogger-demo-1.blogspot.fr/2014_04_01_archive.html

Summary :
So, it seems that my script works only on one type of page (item) in spite of the fact that i inserted the script just before the `</body>` tag and not in if conditions. 
Also it seems that it influence (it is valide) for all videos on the page, not for only the videos within the .post-body (what i wanted).

Can someone tell me how to re-write the script that it does what i would like ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Find all YouTube and Vimeo videos, all types can be added with iframe integration
    var $allVideos = $('iframe[src^="http://player.vimeo.com"], iframe[src^="//www.youtube.com"], object, embed'), $fluidEl = $('.post-body');

    // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
    $allVideos.each(function() {

        $(this)
            .attr('data-aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)
            .removeAttr('height')
            .removeAttr('width');

    });

    // When the window is resized
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

        // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
        $allVideos.each(function() {

            var $el = $(this);
            $el
                .width(newWidth)
                .height(newWidth * $el.attr('data-aspectRatio'));

        });

    // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
    }).resize();

});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think that the script i had is not well-built because it effected the videos and resized to the size of an element of the website... if you indicated 'body', it resized the videos for the body width, if post body, then all of them have been resized to post body width... it is not what i was looking for...

If you are looking for the same thing i was looking for : resize your youtube and vimeo video iframe to its parent div width for 100%, this is a good script which works also in Blogger (source : http://toddmotto.com/fluid-and-responsive-youtube-and-vimeo-videos-with-fluidvids-js/) :

```
(function ( window, document, undefined ) {

  /*
   * Grab all iframes on the page or return
   */
  var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );

  /*
   * Loop through the iframes array
   */
  for ( var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++ ) {

    var iframe = iframes[i],

    /*
       * RegExp, extend this if you need more players
       */
    players = /www.youtube.com|player.vimeo.com/;

    /*
     * If the RegExp pattern exists within the current iframe
     */
    if ( iframe.src.search( players ) > 0 ) {

      /*
       * Calculate the video ratio based on the iframe's w/h dimensions
       */
      var videoRatio        = ( iframe.height / iframe.width ) * 100;

      /*
       * Replace the iframe's dimensions and position
       * the iframe absolute, this is the trick to emulate
       * the video ratio
       */
      iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
      iframe.style.top      = '0';
      iframe.style.left     = '0';
      iframe.width          = '100%';
      iframe.height         = '100%';

      /*
       * Wrap the iframe in a new <div> which uses a
       * dynamically fetched padding-top property based
       * on the video's w/h dimensions
       */
      var wrap              = document.createElement( 'div' );
      wrap.className        = 'fluid-vids';
      wrap.style.width      = '100%';
      wrap.style.position   = 'relative';
      wrap.style.paddingTop = videoRatio + '%';

      /*
       * Add the iframe inside our newly created <div>
       */
      var iframeParent      = iframe.parentNode;
      iframeParent.insertBefore( wrap, iframe );
      wrap.appendChild( iframe );

    }

  }

})( window, document );
```

**Important : you must insert the iframe with its original width and height in pixel (`width="560" height="315"`) that the script could calculate the aspect ration !**